# Client create connection to unknown Server IP

Tags: c, connection, client

I 'm using C language to create a connection from client to server. I use a command:

```
iResult = connect(ServerSocket,(LPSOCKADDR)&addr, nSize);
```

In most of cases, when an server IP (in "addr") is recognized or in local network, it returns the result (fail or Ok) immediately, but if it is an IP out side of local network or non-existed IP, the time out for connection is quite long, cannot response for a real time processing. So, could you please tell me any idea a bout how to set the timeout (several millisecond) for this command? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example in this article:

[How to set a socket connection timeout](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/168704/How-to-set-a-socket-connection-timeout)

Basically you have to use non-blocking socket I/O and use some form of I/O multiplexing (like select or poll).